# Robust ANCOVA literature?

Tags: r, nonparametric, references, ancova, robust

I am looking for some source of information, some articles about Robust ANCOVA. Can you suggest me something? And do you know any source that directly gives information about how to perform various robust ANCOVA with R?

I have seen a citation about Maxwell et al. 1993, an article called *Analysis of Covariance* but I do not find it!

I know Quinn and Keough, *Experimental Design and Data Analysis for Biologists* but they do not give much information about Robust ANCOVA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for material on robust regression. There is lots of it.

ANCOVA, ANOVA and regression are all the same model, really.  In matrix algebra terms they are all

$Y = X\beta + \epsilon$

Answer (score 2):

A general approach is to use cumulative probability ordinal models, the most popular being the proportional odds ordinal logistic model.  See a case study in R in Chapter 15 of my [Handouts](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/CourseBios330).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you  read [Discovering Statistics Using R by Andy Field](https://uk.sagepub.com/en-gb/eur/discovering-statistics-using-r/book236067). He explains  gives information about how to perform various robust ANCOVA in R step by step and it is really easy to follow.